# What is the lattice temperature?

Tags: temperature, lattice-model

I am wondering how the lattice temperature is defined in this context. Is it the temperature on which the energy is big enough to split the crystal in it's components (atoms)?

[image]

Comment: Lattice temperature is the temperature of the crystal lattice. I.E. temperature of the bulk crystal. There are situations where something in the crystal can be at a different temperature.

Comment: @mmesser314 and why does this make it the motion of an atom across the tunnel junction easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lattice temperature is the temperature of the lattice as a whole.